# Duplicates detected when using Database.convertLead in After Update Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

I have an `After Update Trigger` on `Lead` which calls `Database.convertLead`

The code below is run within the trigger:

```
for (Id recordId : leadIds) {

    leadConverter.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
    leadConverter.setConvertedStatus(LeadStatus.Live);
    leadConverter.setLeadId(recordId);

    Database.LeadConvertResult result;

    try {

        result = Database.convertLead(leadConverter);

    } catch (Exception error) {

        Lead failingLead = newMap.get(recordId);
        failingLead.addError(error.getMessage());
    }

    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // do stuff
    } else {

        Lead failingLead = newMap.get(recordId);

        for (Database.Error error : result.getErrors()) {
            failingLead.addError(error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When there is a duplicate, the debug log says:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Use one of these records?

I have a `try catch` around the `Database.convertLead` and I am using `Database.LeadConvertResult` to check `isSuccess()`

But the user gets a generic error:

> There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help.

Which is not helpful when trying to figure out what caused it to fail.

**Question**

1. how can I get the more detailed/specific error message to appear on the screen for the user?

Comment: If you are not catching exception, you will get generic error message, can you add more code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified allOrNone parameter in `result = Database.convertLead(leadConverter);`

Thus it will throw `DMLException` which you have caught.

But `result` will still be null , and thus when you do `if (result.isSuccess())` it will throw NULLPointerException.

As you haven't caught the exception in Trigger you will see the generic message.
You literally dont need the if block.

```
for (Id recordId : leadIds) {

    leadConverter.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
    leadConverter.setConvertedStatus(LeadStatus.Live);
    leadConverter.setLeadId(recordId);

    Database.LeadConvertResult result;

    try {

        result = Database.convertLead(leadConverter);

    } catch (Exception error) {

        Lead failingLead = newMap.get(recordId);
        failingLead.addError(error.getMessage());
    }


}
```